# Documentation for using Kinect SDK for Windows

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, kinect-sdk, feature-extraction

I wish to develop some 3-D structures using kinect, Opencv and c++ on visual studio 2012. I have installed kinect SDK for Windows and its tool-kit. But I don't know how to begin. Where can I get a proper documentation for integrating kinect SDK with Visual Studio and use the commands, libraries, and functions properly as we find in the documentation for opencv.

Also I am trying to use the saved data(in form of .dcl file) of kinect video(rgb, depth, & skeleton). So, how can I access these (.dcl file) and use them for extracting the rgb, depth, skeleton datas again.

Kindly  post the links if you know. Suggestions are most welcomed.

Thanks in advance.